# Code acting weird inside Javascript Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Okay, so I'm opening a Modal where a user needs to confirm a trade, whenever I make the user click the button on the HTML page itself everything seems to work out fine, but whenever I make them click inside the Modal it keeps returning that the trade isn't accepted. (I'm using TingleJS for the Modals)

So, it triggers the failure code instead of the success code, but when executed on the html page it triggers the success code.

Anyone?

This is the code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#confirmButton", function() {
    toastSuccess("<div style='font-size:14px;'>Checking offer..</div>");

    $this = $(this);
    $this.prop("disabled", true);
    var tid = $this.data("tid");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/confirm",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            "tid": tid
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            try {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                if (data.success) {
                    if (data.action == "accept") {
                        toastSuccess("<div style='font-size:14px;'>" + data.result + "</div>");
                    } else {
                        toastError("<div style='font-size:14px;'>" + data.result + "</div>");
                    }
                    $("#offerPanel").slideUp();
                } else {
                    toastError("<div style='font-size:14px;'>" + data.error + "</div>");
                    if (data.count > 0) {
                        cmdm();
                    }
                }
            } catch (err) {
                inlineAlert("error", "Javascript error: " + err);
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            inlineAlert("error", "AJAX error: " + err.statusText);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $this.prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Works fine executed on the page like this (everything works fine):

```
        <button class="" id="confirmButton" data-tid="0">Confirm</button>
```

It does trigger the onclick id but it doesn't return success when a trade is accepted:

```
var pendingModal;
function showPendingModal(data) {
    pendingModal = new tingle.modal({
      footer: false,
      stickyFooter: false,
      cssClass: ['custom-class-1', 'custom-class-2']
    });

    var content = "<div style='text-align:center;font-size:25px;letter-spacing:2px;color:#379639;'>Success!</div>";
    content+= "<div style='font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;text-align:center;color:#2B2E32;margin-bottom:25px;'>You've received an offer from our bot <b>" + data.bot + "</b></div>";
    content+= "<div class='input-box' style='width:35%;background:#e8e8e8;margin:auto;padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:6px;padding-right:6px;'><div style='font-size:12px;letter-spacing:4px;text-align:center;color:#2B2E32'>Security Code</div><div style='font-size:2em;color:black;text-align:center;'>" + data.code + "</div></div>";
    content+= "<div style='margin-top:30px;text-align:center;'><a style='background:#1E1E26;padding:9px 25px 9px 25px;border-radius:35px;color:white;letter-spacing:1px;font-size:25px;' href='https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/" + data.tid + "' target='_blank'>Offer</a>";
    content+= "<a style='margin-left:5px;background:#1E1E26;padding:9px 25px 9px 25px;border-radius:35px;color:white;letter-spacing:1px;font-size:25px;' id='confirmButton' data-tid='0'>Claim</a></div>"

    pendingModal.setContent(content);

    pendingModal.open();
}
```

Comment: So it's triggering the failure code instead of success code?

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with `id="confirmButton"`? IDs have to be unique, you should use a class instead.

Comment: Oh my, what's with all of the inline styles? Time to learn about stylesheets.

Comment: @Barmar, yes I currently have two with the same ID but whenever I remove the other one it still doesn't work, I don't need the other one I was just testing it and it turned out to work, also ye it triggers the failure code instead of the success code.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan, whenever I am testing stuff I usually don't put anything in my stylesheets, and yes I should but I don't feel like removing it again when I decide to not keep the code.

Comment: What's in `data.error`?

Comment: PHP, http://pastebin.com/AxsXPmEH

Comment: I just don't get it, whenever it's in the modal it stops working.

Comment: As a side note - You may wish to look into a javascript 'Templating' Library. Adding HTML dynamically using Strings is not very scalable/readible/makes the kittens cry

Comment: I'd like to get this fixed first, thanks tho :P